# Changing the default tab and page with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner for web design. I need some professionals to help me solve this problem.

Underneath are the JS that I am using to create TABS. I already change the default tab, however I still couldn't figure out how to change the default tab page. Please help !!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var tabLinks = new Array();
var contentDivs = new Array();

function init() {

  // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
  var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
  for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
    if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
      var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
      var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
      tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
      contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
    }
  }

  // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
  // highlight the first tab
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
    tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
    tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
    if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks["order"].className = 'selected';
    i++;
  }

  // Hide all content divs except the first
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
  if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    i++;
  }
}

function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

  // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
  // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'active';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    }
  }

  // Stop the browser following the link
  return false;
}

function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
    if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
  }
}

function getHash( url ) {
  var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
  return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
}

//]]>
</script>
```

**This is the list of tabs**

```
<ul id="tabs">
      <li><a href="#features">Product Features</a></li>
      <li><a  class="selected" href="#order">Order UNIFY Sutures</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#spec">Specifications</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#testi">Testimonials</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#overview">Suture Overview</a></li>  

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code here

```
// Hide all content divs except the first
var i = 0;

for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    i++;
}
```

The zero in the if clause `if ( i != 0 )` defines the active tab page.

You could also look at [jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) which does what you want and is easy to use.

Comment: How do I assign the number for each tab?

Comment: Never mind, I just tried to change the number into "2" and it works !!!! Thank you so much !!! :D

Comment: They are numbered in the order in which they appear in the page, starting with zero.

Comment: Hi Raidri. Do you know the how to create subtabs?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the showTab function with this:

```
function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );      
  selectTab(selectedId);
  return false;
}

function selectTab(selectedId) {

  // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
  // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'active';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    }
  }
}
```

Then, to select a specific tab, call something like this:

```
selectTab('spec');
```

EDIT: changed  selectTab('#spec');  to  selectTab('spec');

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRjrJ/1/)

Comment: Sorry...minor syntax error: changed selectTab('#spec'); to selectTab('spec');